# Talend Second Sequence number

Tags: talend

i've got the following data:

```
ID;NAME;SKILL 
1;JOE;XML 
1;JOE;JAVA 
1;JOE;ORACLE 
2;JOHN;JAVA 
2;JOHN;API
```

I need a counter that will give me this structure:

```
ID;NAME;COUNTER;SKILL
1;JOE;1;XML
1;JOE;2;JAVA
1;JOE;3;ORACLE
2;JOHN;1;JAVA
2;JOHN;2;API
```

How can i achieve that in Talend? I tried to use a Number.sequence but i dont know how to get the dependency with the column ID. So every time a new id occures i need to reset the Sequence Number.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in following way.

yourInput---tJavaRow---tMap--youroutput

1. Create context variable named as oldID as int.\
2. In tJavaRow add following code.

   if(!input_row.ID.equalsIgnoreCase(context.oldID)){
       Numeric.resetSequence("i", 0);
       context.oldID=input_row.ID;
    }
3. Add tmap after tJavaRow and add additional column with name COUNTER
4. In COUNTER column add following code.

   Numeric.sequence("i",1, 1);
5. Now execute your job will get expected output.

my output.

```
[statistics] connected
1|JOE|1|XML 
1|JOE|2|JAVA 
1|JOE|3|ORACLE 
2|JOHN|1|JAVA 
2|JOHN|2|API
[statistics] disconnected
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way to do it : you can have a schema like input->tMap->output.
Then in tMap, just add a new Integer column "counter" and fill it with `Numeric.sequence(row1.NAME,1,1)`

It will automatically restart the sequence every time the input name changes.